# How can i retrieve username and password when retrieving Azure Database details via Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I can list Azure databases as follows:

```
  $servers = Get-AzSqlServer
   foreach($server in $servers)
   {
      $databases = Get-AzSqlDatabase -ServerName $server.ServerName -ResourceGroupName 
       $server.ResourceGroupName 
        foreach($db in $databases){
         Write-Host "Server " $db.ServerName  "Database " $db.DatabaseName 
            $server.SqlAdministratorLogin "SqlAdminPwd " 
            $server.SqlAdministratorPassword
            Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $db.ServerName -Database $db.DatabaseName - 
           Username <azuredb_admin_username> -Password 
                    <azuredb_admin_password> -Query 
              'select * from [dbo].[TableName]' 
       }
    }
```

$server.SqlAdministratorPassword is empty which is understandable.
But in the next line I invoke a sqlcmd which requires the password.

How can i get and use the password ?

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell query should require login credential implicitly or explicitly through the command line.  There are couple of ways to pass credentials.

1. Store credentials in credentials manager and fetch the information from there
   example:

   ```
    $psCred = Get-StoredCredential -Target "ABCD" –AsCredentialObject
   ```
2. Here is the code snippet to get the password using PowerShell

   ```
    $serverName = $db.ServerName
    $DB = $db.DatabaseName  
    $credential = Get-Credential 
    $userName = $credential.UserName.Replace("\","")  
    $pass = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().password   
    invoke-sqlcmd -query "select @@Servername" -database      $DB -serverinstance $servername -username $username -password $pass -Query 'select * from [dbo].[TableName]'
   ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: These options wont work efficiently as it requires user input. I dont want the user to input any details input as this will run on a daily basis in CI/CD pipeline job ie I want to automate this job

Comment: The username is the azure sql server admin user name and the password is the azure sql server admin password

Comment: Can i use a AD account instead of username and password ?

Comment: if intent use to automate via CICD refer this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-azure-sql-access-token-authentication-from-azure-devops-pipelines-344fa7dafa49)

Comment: I have tried that I get the following error: Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'. Incorrect or invalid token.